# Batch file variable value not available until outside of loop

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to write a batch file that will search through a directory for *.pdf file extensions then convert them to *.tif file extensions with ImageMagic. I am able to do this if there is one PDF file in the directory, but if there are more than one I can't figure out how to convert them with the correct name. The problem is that **within the loop**, the `fName` variable doesn't appear to be assigned, but **outside the loop**, it has a value...

Here is the code that works for a single PDF file and works for multiple, but the name containts ".pdf":

```
echo off
set dSource=C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Research\Journal Article\Figures
set fType=*.pdf
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b "%dSource%\%fType%"') do (
    rem remove extension from file name, set value to variable:
    set fName=%%~nf

    rem call ImageMagic to convert to TIFF
    rem convert -compose copy -density 300 -alpha off "%%f" "%%f.tif"
    rem above line (when uncommented) lets multiple TIFF images to be produced, but they are *.pdf.tif

    rem convert -compose copy -density 300 -alpha off "%fName%.pdf" "%fName%.tif"
    rem above line (when uncommented) does not work because fName has no value...

    rem variable value does not appear to be assigned within loop:
    echo.file name within loop: %fName%
)
echo.file name after loop: %fName% 
rem outside loop, variable value is now available...
rem convert -compose copy -density 300 -alpha off "%fName%.pdf" "%fName%.tif" 
rem above line of code works, but only for the last file name with *.pdf discovered in directory
pause
```

Comment: Is that 'convert' statement in your for loop?

Comment: Hey @kenny, yes I would like the convert statement in the loop to convert multiple figures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable delayed expansion if you need to set a variable and use it in the same loop, and then refer to the variable in the loop using `!` instead of `%`:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set dSource=C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Research\Journal Article\Figures
set fType=*.pdf
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b "%dSource%\%fType%"') do (
    set fName=%%~nf
    echo fName in the loop:  !fName!
)
echo fName out of the loop:  %fName%
```

Google "batch delayed expansion" for details.

Answer (score 0):

In your case a solution is to replace this:

```
convert -compose copy -density 300 -alpha off "%%f" "%%f.tif"
```

with this:

```
convert -compose copy -density 300 -alpha off "%%f" "%%~dpnf.tif"
rem or "%%~nf.tif" to save them all in the current folder.
```

The drawback with delayed expansion is that a `!` character becomes more difficult to process in a filename or path or string.

Comment: Thank you for responding @foxidrive, this is also a valid solution. I initially wanted to store the file names in a variable (array?) so I have access to them outside the loop to make edits with IrfanView via the batch file, but so far this has not proven to be necessary because I can just add code within the existing loop!